# Get the second last word from right in the below string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to find the second to last word from right in the below string in SQL Server.

```
Declare @text as varchar(60)

Set @text = 'Next Generation Customer Service'
```

I want output as 'Customer'

Can anyone please help?
Thanks in advance.

I tried using `charindex`, `reverse` etc

Comment: `I tried using charindex, reverse etc` Can you show us what you have tried ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
select reverse(substring(reverse(@text), 
          charindex(' ',reverse(@text)),
          charindex(' ',reverse(trim(reverse(substring(reverse(@text), 
          charindex(' ',reverse(@text)),len(@text))))))))
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, 
**[including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) 
really helps to improve the quality of your post**. Remember that you are 
answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might 
not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd 
your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both 
the code and the explanations!

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked like a magic. Would you mind sharing the logic you used to get this output.